# JS/TS func to Dart func

Tags: javascript, dart

I want to convert it to dart code but I dnt understand ternary operator in that code

```
const getPagination = (page, size) => {
  const limit = size ? +size : 3
  const from = page ? page * limit : 0
  const to = page ? from + size - 1 : size - 1

  return { from, to }
}
```

if you can tell me what code do line by line ??

Comment: If you have `const x = a ? b : c`, it can be read as `let x = c; // default value` `if (a) { x = b; // if a condition is met, use another value }`. So on the first line, `limit` will be `3` by default, unless `size` is set, in which case we'll use `+size`, which is a way of converting it to a number

Comment: so its a null check ? its make sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more idiomatic Dart implementation of the same code could be:

```dart
Range getPagination([int page = 0, int size = 3]) {
  RangeError.checkNotNegative(page, "page");
  if (size <= 0) size = 3;
  var from = page * size;
  var to = from + size - 1;
  return Range(from, to);
}

class Range {
  final int from;
  final int to;
  Range(this.from, this.to);
}
```

This allows you to call with no arguments, but not with `null` as explicit argument. So don't do that.

If you omit the size, the size is `3`. That's more useful than finding a limit if size is `null` or `0`, but then use `size` anyway in the `to` computation, instead of `limit`.

Using a list of integers as a pair of integers is not the Dart way. I'd create a class, like here, or wait for records and use a proper `(int, int)` tuple.

Dart lists, and maps, are much more expensive data structures than JavaScript "objects". A small class is what corresponds to the anonymous object `{from, to}` in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah its much better using default value and limit is a bit redundant, since I plan to refactor code later

Comment: but why check if size <0 to 3 since you already have default value ??

Comment: Because someone could pass in `0` or `-1`, and that would be bad. The alternative is to just do `RangeError.checkValueInInterval(size, 1, null, "size");`, and throw for bad values. The original would convert `0` to `3` because of how JS decides "truth", so I went for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

so I convert it by looking at TS play code

```
void main() {
  List<int> getPagination(int? page, int? size) {
  int? limit = size ?? 3;
  int? from = page != null ? page * limit : 0;
  int? to = page != null ? (from + size!) - 1 : (size! - 1);

  return [from, to];
}
  print(getPagination(0, 10));
}
```

and its works thx to @blex